# The Strange character generator not using the same rules as the rulebook

Tags: character-creation, tools, the-strange

I have a question about the rpg *The Strange*.
I'm using the [character creator app of the official website](http://chargen.thestrangerpg.com/app/), but when creating a Vector, the options proposed are not the same that the ones using the core rulebook.

When I level up the vector using the application, starting from the Tier 2, I receive one additional weapon training per Tier up to the Tier 6, while it is not the case in the core rulebook.

Do somebody knows if it is an error in the application, or in the rules?
Is there an errata of the rulebook out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I believe the book is wrong.

You should gain additional weapon training for free *every tier* (called **Skill with Attacks**). On the book, that ability is listed as a **Maneuver** for every tier other than third, but should actually be an ability gained every tier.

Why i believe it is wrong? Because *Skill with Attacks* as a maneuver is terrible on *every tier* compared to every other maneuver option available for your character.

At 6th tier you have a maneuver that **allows your character to act a second time** (or third/fourth if you can pay the cost), or you can pick an additional weapon training that will grant you +3 on your checks with a specific type of weapon, which is no better than the one gained at 1st tier. Nope.

And this is also the case for **Numenera** and *glaives* (the setting's equivalent to *vectors*), they gain *Skill with Attacks* every tier for free. The classes between the two books are not exactly the same, they have different abilities and flavor, but they are *mechanically equivalent*.

For *weavers*, it does make sense being a maneuver, and they can only pick it twice (3rd and 6th tiers), which also happens to Numenera's *jacks* on the very same tiers.